# Read gzip from Azure StorageStreamDownloader

Tags: azure-blob-storage, gzip

I would like to read a gzip that I have downloaded from an Azure blob storage:

```
myStorageStreamDownloaderObject = blob_service_client.
    get_container_client('myContainer').
    download_blob(myBlob.json.gzip)
```

(Note that the file contains a json and it has extension .gzip (not .gz).)

**Attempt 1:**

```
import gzip as gzip
contents = myStorageStreamDownloaderObject.readall()
result   = gzip.decompress(contents)
```

The yields:

```
contents = b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\xbd\x9d=\xb3\xe6\xb8q\x85\xff\xcb\xc4\xab)|4>8\x99...
result   = b''
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd

with BytesIO() as input_blob:
    myStorageStreamDownloaderObject.readinto(input_blob)
    input_blob.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(input_blob, compression='gzip')
```

This yields:

```
EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

**It does work with Spark**

```
df = spark.
    read.option("compression", "gzip").
    schema(json_schema).
    json([f"wasbs://{container_name}@geoexportpreprodanwb.blob.core.windows.net/{blob_name}"])
```

This nicely returns a dataframe with 275 rows. But I am looking for a solution without Spark.

Comment: where are you executing the above code? databricks?

Comment: Yes Databricks. But it turned out that did not matter. I found the cause and just posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had a very basic cause:
I did not realize `myStorageStreamDownloaderObject` is like a generator.

My full code was something like this:

```
contents = myStorageStreamDownloaderObject.readall()
print(contents)
# This yields: b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\xbd\x9d=\xb3\xe6\xb8q\x85\xff\xcb\xc4\xab)|4>8\x99...

contents = myStorageStreamDownloaderObject.readall()
result   = gzip.decompress(contents)
print(result)
# This yields: b''
```

But because `myStorageStreamDownloaderObject` is like a generator I should not have called it twice. The following does work:

```
contents = myStorageStreamDownloaderObject.readall()
print(contents)
result = gzip.decompress(contents)
print(result)
```

(My apologies for inaccurately summarizing my code in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

> Read a gzip that I have downloaded from an Azure blob storage

You can use the below code to read JSON(gzip) files from Azure blob storage.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
import gzip
import  pandas  as  pd
from  pandas  import  DataFrame
import json

# Set the connection string and container name
connection_string = "<Your-connection-string>"
container_name = "test"
blob_name = "student1.json.gzip"

# Create a BlobServiceClient object
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

# Get a BlobClient object for the gzip file
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=blob_name)

# Download the gzip file as a stream
stream_downloader = blob_client.download_blob()
contents =stream_downloader.readall()
result = gzip.decompress(contents)
json_data = json.loads(result)
print(json_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Register': {'Name': {'1': 'azure', '2': 'aws', '3': 'gcp', '4': 'AI', '5': 'robotics'}, 'ID': {'1': '0001', '2': '0002', '3': '0003', '4': '0004', '5': '0005'}, 'Domain': {'1': 'Microsoft', '2': 'Amazon', '3': 'google', '4': 'sysca', '5': 'IRobot'}, 'Rank': {'1': '0002', '2': '0001', '3': '0003', '4': '0004', '5': '0005'}}}
```

[image]

To read the file, you can use **`Dataframe`** in code by using **`print(Dataframe(json_data))`**.

**Output:**

```
                                                 Register
Domain  {'1': 'Microsoft', '2': 'Amazon', '3': 'google...
ID      {'1': '0001', '2': '0002', '3': '0003', '4': '...
Name    {'1': 'azure', '2': 'aws', '3': 'gcp', '4': 'A...
Rank    {'1': '0002', '2': '0001', '3': '0003', '4': '...
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Frank kindly share what went wrong with this solution so that I can correct it?".

Comment: Hi Venkatesan, thanks for the useful example code! However the cause of the problem was more basic than you might expect. I just posted the solution. Hope it helps other Azure beginners like me ;-)